# How to controll rss feed in D7?

Tags: 7, feeds

Could anyone please tell me that how to control RSS feed in D7, because even without my knowledge D7 has created a RSS feed for my site.eg `http://wwww.mysite.com/rss.xml`

Even though in that feed my page contents are not selected but some un-nessaary items are selected like News letter, Poll and image jCarousel details. I'm 100% sure that I didn't select these items to generate feed but I don't understand how get it involved.

Also if I want to select the required page content link to display on the RSS feed how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all nodes opted to "Promoted to front page" will be shown in the global feed.

[image]

This is a per-node setting, and you can control the default value at **Admin > Structure > Content Types > [type] > Edit**.

Also, if you want to take control which fields (and each field's display) should be shown in the feed, as a feed item, go to "Manage display" tab at the node type edit page and enable `RSS` custom display. There you can hide/show fields of the feed.

You can, as an advanced step, override this page with a View (see default taxonomy and front page/feed views) or even unset the menu router item completely with a custom module, implementing [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

There is a module, [RSS Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/rss_permissions), that you can restrict access to feeds if you are interested.

Comment: thanks man, you just cleared the long time confusion in my D7 site.

Answer (score 1):

To default RSS feed page goes for example every node with promote to front page flag set to true.

You can use Views to create your own, highly configurable RSS feeds. If you want even more control you can use this module https://drupal.org/project/views_rss.

You can override default RSS feed with a Views one too

Comment: Thanks man, since I got solution I'll try this on my next D7 site.